# Auth0 / tedious unable to connect to a public SQL Server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, tcp, auth0, tedious

I'm using Auth0 with a custom database, when adding a Sql Server script (that uses tedious) when a user gets created I receive following error message:

```
[Error] Failed to get response from SQL Server Browser on 'serverIp'
```

Connection object:

```
var connection = sqlserver.connect({
    userName:  'userName',
    password:  'passWord',
    server:    'serverIp',
    /* port parameter is not needed because 1433 is used as default */
    options:  {
        database: 'databaseName',
        instanceName: 'sqlexpress' /* when removing this the error becomes: timeout : failed to connect to 'serverIp' in 15000ms */
    }
});
```

The serverIp is the IPv4 Address retrieved by using the ipconfig command. I enabled TCP/IP and the SQL Server Browser, my firewall is also temporarily disabled for testing purposes and the IPAll has TCP Port 1433.

[image]

[image]

It is possible for me to open the SQL Server on another computer so how does it happen that Auth0 / tedious does not allow a connection?

Comment: Why do you pass serverIp as "serverIp" string? you should pass in numbers and dots (for example, 127.0.0.1). For now the network library asks SQL Server Browser for the port for instance with the name "serverIp" but there is no such an instance

Comment: I read your error that said: Failed to get response from SQL Server Browser on 'serverIp'. And this error cites 'serverIp' instead of IP

Comment: All places where my IP gets shown, I changed it to the string serverIp (so also in the error message). The serverIp (192.168,..) needs to get inserted as a string, else the object is invalid and I receive the error: Invalid response code from the auth0-sandbox: HTTP 400. Unexpected number

Comment: That is strange, the fact is when you use the real IP, NOTHING should be passed to SQL Server Browser. The network library goes directly to this IP-address. And SQL Server Browser does not expects IP-address, it expects Instance Name, and returns its port

Comment: Try to not pass in instanceName: 'sqlexpress'. Your connection string should contain only IP and, if you want, you can specify 1433 port.

Comment: When removing the instanceName option and adding the port, I receive following error: timeout : failed to connect to 192.168....:1433 in 15000ms. So it tries to connect to the correct IP and port but gets a timeout, the log also doesn't show any more information.

Comment: The log cannot show anything if the server is not reached because it's server to write to the log. Are you sure your server indeed listens on 1433? Maybe you changed the port when SQL Server was already running and forget to restart it? You can find the port actually in use in first rows of error log

Comment: To test that the server is on port 1433 I used the telnet command: telnet 192.168... 1433 and it only allows a connection if the port is 1433. The same happens when trying connect to the server using SSMS where only 192.168...,1433 works and not for example 1434. I did a SQL Server restart and my firewall is still disabled but still no luck.

Comment: At this point I suspect your network library. It does smth strange. It should not even pass to SQL Server Browser but go directly to IP,port. But if it insists on Browser, try to pass in server name if format ip\sqlexpress. And the error if it will occur must cite ip\sqlexpress, not just serverIp. By the way, did you open UDP 1434 port?

Comment: I tried it with all possible scenarios (with instanceName, without port,..) but it all results in an error looking like this: [Error] Failed to lookup instance on 192.168...\sqlexpress : Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 192.168...\sqlexpress. My firewall is disabled, should this not be enough to open the 1434 port, how else should I do it? Keep in mind that I can open the SQL Server on another computer from SSMS.

Comment: If firewall is disabled,it's enough. I still think that you use **incorrect network library**. To test if your SQL Server browser is working properly try to connect using SSMS providing this connection string: TCP:192.168...\sqlexpress. This provides no port and will be passed to SQL Server Browser, in case it works well it will be resolved in correct port number and connection will succeed

Comment: TCP:192.168...\sqlexpress in SSMS worked on both computers and it gets connected to the server.

Comment: So there is NOTHING wrong wth SQL Servrer, SQL Server Browser and firewall. All that is wrong is your connection string or the network library that elaborates it.

Comment: I found this in another topic. It seems that this "tediuos" has problems with named instances: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3097.The only thing is clear: it's definitely not SQL Server issue...